# previous, current and next 3 quarters?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get previous, current and next 3 quarters base on current quarter and year.

Example : Current Quarter = 3  & Year = 2014
I want Output,

Q2-2014
Q3-2014
Q4-2014
Q1-2015
Q2-2015

I am trying as under but output is **NOT** correct and also how to club previous quarter?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int generateQuater = 5;

        int currentQuater = 3;
        int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

        List<string> lstQuaterYear = new List<string>();

        for (int i = generateQuater; i > 0; i--)
        {
            lstQuaterYear.Add(string.Format("Q{0}-{1}", currentQuater, currentYear));
            if (--currentQuater == 0)
            {
                currentQuater = 4;
                currentYear++;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Hint: use DateTime.AddMonths().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < generateQuater; i++)
    {

        if(currentQuater%5 ==0)
        {
            currentQuater = 1;
            currentYear++;
        }

        lstQuaterYear.Add(string.Format("Q{0}-{1}", currentQuater%5, currentYear));

        currentQuater++;

    }
```

Modulo 5 will return values in the range [0,4]. Quarter 0 can be interpreted as quarter 1 of the next year. Therefore, we handle that case by setting `currentQuater` to 1 and incrementing `currentYear`. This will go through the 4 quarters of each year, and on the 5th one, it will move to next year and restart counting from 1.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/EWJBVQ76413)

Comment: is there any chance to add previous quarter. I know we can add this to the list before the loop. Thanks!

Comment: Does this assume Q1 starts on January 1?

Comment: I would say yes, because that seems to be OP's assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this code with help of Tieson.

Question : Any other/linq approach for subjected problem also welcome.

```
int generateQuater = 4;
        int currentQuater = 3;
        int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

        List<string> lstQuaterYear = new List<string>();
        //previous Quater
        lstQuaterYear.Add(String.Format("Q{0}-{1}", (currentQuater - 1) + (((1) / 4) * 4), currentYear - ((1) / 4)));

        for (int i = 0; i < generateQuater; i++)
        {

            if (currentQuater % 5 == 0)
            {
                currentQuater = 1;
                currentYear++;
            }
            //current and next 3 Quater
            lstQuaterYear.Add(string.Format("Q{0}-{1}", currentQuater % 5, currentYear));
            currentQuater++;
        }
```